# KSZ9896c Ethernet Switch Packet Loss

Tags: ethernet

I built a shield for my Raspberry Pi with an ethernet switch. I used a KSZ9896c as the switch and 4 LAN ports. I attached a sensor via ethernet to one of the ports. Unfortunately I get packet loss after a few minutes. At the start of the transmission everything seems to work fine.
[image]

The wierd thing is that I don't get any packet loss when I attach a second switch (TP-Link TL-SG1016PE) between the PI and the KSZ9896c.

I checked the voltages and clock signal of the switch and everything is fine. I also read the MIB register of the KSZ9896c and I didn't get any CRC counters.

Do you think the packet register might be overflown? Do have any idea what I can try next?

Comment: Observation #1: **Don't trust your Ethernet Switch.** (https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/25/six-whys-or-never-trust-your-network-switch/)  Observation #2: **Don't trust your Ethernet Switch.** (https://labjack.com/forums/t7/gigabit-ethernet-switch-issues-t7)

Comment: I solved it. By default a so caleld eee setting (energy efficient ethernet) is set by the pi. you have deactivate this with  

sudo ethtool --set-eee eth0 eee off